# HTTP Post dynamic data to and from Google App Engine

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, post, go

I want to write an application in Java that will communicate with Google App Engine app written in Go by sending and receiving dynamic data. The data is not human readable (as in, not ASCII, Unicode or the like) and ranges from a couple bytes to about 1MB.

I am wondering if it is possible to send such data to and from GAE using Post method directly, or is it better to just encode it as a hex dump and transfer is at text (thusly increasing its size a couple times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, of course. Just like an HTTP response, an HTTP request can contain a payload of any sort (unless it's a GET or other method that doesn't permit a body); just set the content-type appropriately and send the data in the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

If people can POST 10mb photos to Facebook, then I don't see why you can't do that with your data :)